# Select de valor de mês anterior

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, oracle, sql-select

DIRETO AO PONTO, TENHO ESSE SCRIPT.

```
SELECT FILIAL,
       COD_REDUZIDO,
       COD_PL_CONTA,
       NOME_CONTA,
       ANO,
       MES,
 VALOR_CREDITO,
       VALOR_DEBITO,
       SALDO
  FROM (  SELECT CODFILIAL
                     FILIAL,
                 PS.CODREDUZIDO_PC
                     COD_REDUZIDO,
                 M.NOME_CONTA
                     NOME_CONTA,
                 M.CODCONTA_PC
                     COD_PL_CONTA,
                 PS.ANO
                     ANO,
                 PS.MES
                     MES,
                 SUM (NVL (PS.VALORCREDITO, 0))
                     VALOR_CREDITO,
                 SUM (NVL (PS.VALORDEBITO, 0))
                     VALOR_DEBITO,
                 SUM (
                     CASE
                         WHEN M.NATUREZA = 'D'
                         THEN
                             NVL (PS.VALORDEBITO, 0) - NVL (PS.VALORCREDITO, 0)
                         ELSE
                             NVL (PS.VALORCREDITO, 0) - NVL (PS.VALORDEBITO, 0)
                     END)
                     SALDO,
                 M.NATUREZA
            FROM PCSALDO PS
                 LEFT JOIN PCMODELOPC M ON PS.CODREDUZIDO_PC = M.CODREDUZIDO_PC
        GROUP BY CODFILIAL,
                 PS.CODREDUZIDO_PC,
                 M.NOME_CONTA,
                 M.CODCONTA_PC,
                 PS.ANO,
                 PS.MES,
                 M.NATUREZA
        ORDER BY ANO DESC)
```

Como faço pra colocar uma coluna SALDO_INICIAL onde o valor na coluna seria o valor o mês anterior? Por exemplo: na coluna em que mês é 1 mostraria o saldo do mes 12 do ano anterior como saldo inicial.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Obrigado Leandro Paixão epla edição

Comment: Tente com Analytic Functions LAG LEAD https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions082.htm#SQLRF00652  https://www.javatpoint.com/mysql-lead-and-lag-function

Comment: Adicione apenas a  tag a que se refere é Oracle ou Mysql....

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Veja se isso resolve, coloque abaixo do SALDO no seu select.

```sql
(SELECT SUM (CASE
                 WHEN M.NATUREZA = 'D'
                     THEN
                         NVL (PS.VALORDEBITO, 0) - NVL (PS.VALORCREDITO, 0)
                     ELSE
                         NVL (PS.VALORCREDITO, 0) - NVL (PS.VALORDEBITO, 0)
                     END)
                     SALDO_ANTERIOR 
          FROM PCSALDO PS LEFT JOIN PCMODELOPC M ON PS.CODREDUZIDO_PC = M.CODREDUZIDO_PC
               WHERE RPS.MES = TRUNC(add_months(RPS.MES, -1), 'MONTH')) SALDO_ANTERIOR
```